# Fancybox: using a background image

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, fancybox

I'm having a bit of trouble with fancybox on the photo's section.

At the moment when you click on one of the images it loads the same size as on the page (the image is actually much larger) and also removes the div from the page.

**I want to load the background image of the div at it's full size into the fancybox.**

```
<div class="main-photo fancybox" rel="group" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $photo; ?>');">
   <a href="<?php echo the_sub_field('photo'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/picture-of-health-photo-frame.png" height="240" width="360" />
   </a>
</div>
```

The `img` within the link is actually the photo frame, which I don't want to be included within the fancybox.

Comment: Can you do that just put the current background image inside `DIV` and give it the facybox class and if you want the photo frame background for the photo then assing that to as a background of `DIV`....it seems like a design logic issue not related to facny box

Comment: @Peeyush Is there no way to adjust the jquery? I have to have the divs set up in this way as it handles variable image sizes from Wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `class="fancybox"` to the anchor `<a>` tag, not to the `<div>` tag so :

```
<div class="main-photo" rel="group" style="background-image:url('<?php echo $photo; ?>');">
   <a class="fancybox" href="<?php echo the_sub_field('photo'); ?>">
      <img src="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/images/picture-of-health-photo-frame.png" height="240" width="360" />
   </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Can't believe I didn't try the class on the link!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked, with Firebug or any other inspector, that the image being loaded by Fancybox is actually the "big image" that you want?

Because I have, and you are loading the exact same image. :)

Comment: That's actually correct except the thumbnail image has some CSS making it that size whereas the actual image is 533px by 800px. How can I make the image it's actual size in fancybox?

Comment: Is this an answer? looks like a question or a comment to me.

Comment: This should be a **comment**, not an answer!

Comment: @SonerGönül - you need 50 reputation to be able to comment on any post.

Comment: @ChrisF I know it. So, he should get 50 reputation and after that he should make his comment. I believe this is not excuse for putting as an answer this. A lot of people who join this site nearly make this kind of mistakes.

Comment: @SonerGönül - You may know that, but if the OP doesn't your statement causes more confusion.

Comment: @ChrisF Of course, that's why I always try to write links like [FAQ], [ask], [answer] to my comments on this kind of situations..